# If I want to create a GUI which displays exactly the same data as TOP command does in LINUX, where do I get the data from?

Tags: linux, python, gui, top

I found out that I can get the PID(first column) from the /proc/[pid]/stat file, first column. I am not sure where can I find the rest of the attributes. And my guess is we need to calculate the %CPU and %MEM from some other attributes. Can someone please help me with this? 
My GUI should look exactly like top. I am using Python3 and ttk for the GUI.

Comment: top.c maybe? Open source benefit!

Answer (score 4):

If you type:

```
strace -o outfile top
```

it will run `top` as usual, while tracing all the system calls it makes and placing the result in `outfile`. The files it opens are visible as calls to the `open(2)` system call. After running this, you should quit `top` quickly, since it will keep appending lots of data and just a few seconds worth are enough to tell you what it reads.

Running this quickly on my own system, it appears most of the data are from `/proc/<pid>/stat`, `/proc/<pid>/status` and `/proc/<pid>/statm`. Some searching and experimentation should allow you to determine the formats of these.

Answer (score 1):

man 5 proc has a lot of good detail what you can find in your proc filesystem.

The procps library is basically a bunch of things that read files in that filesystem, parse them, and set variables or structures depending on what it finds. Generally the answer to "why does ps/top etc show value X" is "because that's what was in file Z"

We are actively re-working the libproc/libprocps/libwhatwillwecallitnext library of procps to make it much more like a normal library.

Currently there will be only C bindings (because we need those) but perhaps in the future there might be other ones as well. The API needs to settle down first and we will need to get the new library out there and see it works in the real world, but then we can look into that.

Looking at top source is another idea, the problem is if you roll your own you need to track all the things the kernel folk do to procfs, while with the library that's our headache.